# Fountain code and online code

Tags: terminology, definition, coding-theory

Are [fountain code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_code) and [online code](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-online.pdf) the same? It seems to me they have the same property, which is used in lossy channel and generate unlimited encoded block.

If they are the same, then what encoding technique are they using? I ask this because I don't see how a matrix with only entries $0$ and $1$ can generate unlimited encoded blocks. If possible, can someone give me an example of such a matrix?

Remark: In the online code's paper, it stated that the degree of a check block (encoded block). Can anyone explain to me how to choose such degree? I don't understand what is stated in the paper.

Comment: They're not the same: An online code is a type of fountain code. There exist other fountain codes, such as LT codes and Raptor codes.

Comment: So fountain code is a group of codes? online is just one of it?

Comment: That's correct. By the way, I'm not sure what matrix you're referring to in the question. I don't see any matrices in the *Online codes* paper.

Comment: In the paper, it stated that online codes can generate unlimited encoded blocks. But I'm not sure how to generate it using matrix. Or do we have other way to do so?